# How can I send a print command from a winCE device to a PCL printer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-ce, printer-control-language, smart-device

I'm developing an application for Honeywell Dolphin 6100, a mobile computer with a barcode scanner that uses Windows CE 5.0 like OS.

I want to add an option that can take a text file (**.pdf, .txt, .docx, etc**) from a "**openFileDialog**" component and send a print command to a PCL Laser via network or bluetooth to print the document.

I don't know where to start. Can any one help me with this !?!!!

Answer (score 1):

Open port 9100 on the printer and send the data.  Otherwise, start an LPR session over 515.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should help :

[Smart Device Print Engine for Compact Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6704/Smart-Device-Print-Engine-for-Compact-Framework)